# Golang: How to get computing time using pprof within a web server

Tags: go, pprof

I have built a web server and did an **ab(apache benchmark)** test. Now I want to know the computing time of each part.

I used the `go tool pprof url:port/xxx` and get the profile of this program, but it does not tell me the computing time(only has memory). Following is the results:

```
(pprof) top10
1827.59MB of 1978.12MB total (92.39%)
Dropped 175 nodes (cum <= 9.89MB)
Showing top 10 nodes out of 48 (cum >= 43.50MB)
  flat  flat%   sum%        cum   cum%
  769.54MB 38.90% 38.90%   769.54MB 38.90%  reflect.unsafe_New
  459.08MB 23.21% 62.11%   459.08MB 23.21%  services/semanticnew.TopicProbCounter.Update
  189.17MB  9.56% 71.67%  1081.21MB 54.66% github.com/golang/protobuf/proto.(*Buffer).dec_slice_struct
  122MB  6.17% 77.84%      122MB  6.17%  github.com/golang/protobuf/proto.(*Buffer).dec_int32
  107.56MB  5.44% 83.28%   107.56MB  5.44% github.com/garyburd/redigo/redis.(*conn).readReply
  68.13MB  3.44% 86.72%   527.21MB 26.65%  services/semanticnew.caculApPoiScore

  40.51MB  2.05% 88.77%    40.51MB  2.05%  runtime.malg
  28.59MB  1.45% 90.22%    28.59MB  1.45%  net/http.newBufioWriterSize
  22.50MB  1.14% 91.35%       23MB  1.16%  redismanage.(*Manager).getRequest
  20.50MB  1.04% 92.39%    43.50MB  2.20%  redismanage.(*Manager).GetRequest
```

In my web program, I have added the following code:

```
f, _ := os.Create("x.cpuprofile")
pprof.StartCPUProfile(f)
defer pprof.StopCPUProfile()
```

but it still does not work.

I have checked http://blog.golang.org/profiling-go-programs, but the `xxx.prof` file confused me. How can I generate this `xxx.prof` file? And the author used `go tool pprof xxx xxx.prof`, does it mean that `xxx` is the binary file which generated by `xxx.go`?

Anyway, the target is getting the computing time, but how? Do I have to generate this `xxx.prof` file to achieve this goal?

Many thanks

Comment: notes: don't use `ab`, it's not good, and can't keep up with a basic go server. A CPU profile does  not specifically measure "computing time". pprof is a sampling profiler, and you're counting samples.

Comment: Also, you created the `xxx.prof` file in your second example, but named it `x.cpuprofile`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had success using Dmitry's advice from here: https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2014/05/10/debugging-performance-issues-in-go-programs

> You merely need to import net/http/pprof, and collect profiles with:
>
> $ go tool pprof --text mybin http://myserver:6060:/debug/pprof/profile

The net/http/pprof is imported solely for its side effects, so you can use

```
import (
   ...
   _ "net/http/pprof"
)
```

Aside from "mybin" and "myserver" you also need to substitute your port number in and remove the trailing colons after the port number.
E.g. for my pet project, the command is

```
go tool pprof http://127.0.0.1:8000/debug/pprof/profile
```

You'll then get a pprof archive created which you can explore interactively through pprof, or you can use an external tool - personally I prefer the built-in capabilities.

*Note that https://github.com/golang/go/issues/13841 and https://github.com/golang/go/issues/6047 are existing problems with the combination of pprof and some kernels.*